# Join a json value with a column in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to join a column with a json value. The problem is the json value is within square brackets and its a uuid. Table name that has the json column(column named `json`) is `department` and the other table name is `staff`. The json column value would be like below,

```
{"title":"Manager","alternativeTitle":null,"departmentIds":["c8098u43-7d9a-3789-gt56-r78009v4r345"]}
```

I would like to query the `departmentIds` from the `json` column and join it with `staffdepartmentID` column in the `staff` table.

My query for the join

```
from staff s
join department d on d.json ->> departmentIds::json = s.staffdepartmentID
```

The problem I am facing is that I dont know how to remove those square brackets. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square braquets within a json data correspond to an array.
You can access any element of the array based on its position starting with 0 for the first element : `array->0`

So for your query you can do :

```
from staff s
inner join department d
on d.json -> 'departmentIds'->>0 = s.staffdepartmentID :: text
```